# Looking foward or back in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, navigation, foreach

I am rendering navigation from a 2 dimensional array, using lists, as shown:

```
<ul> <li>parent 
<ul> <li>level 1</li> <li>level 1

<ul> <li>level 3</li> </ul>

</li> </ul>

<li> </ul>

</li> </ul>
```

Anyway to close the `<li>` and `</ul>` correctly I find I need some data from the next array in the foreach sequence. How can I retrieve this?

Comment: Please provide [minimal sample code](http://sscce.org/) to show us what you're doing.

Comment: you're processing an array, you have ALL the data in the array at your disposal at ANY given time.

Comment: Since you are working with, what I assume is categories, I would suggest looking into this: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html  that way your categories are all setup for you via the query etc. A good read either way :)

Comment: backward is simple though. just save the previous element.

Comment: If I understand your problem right, you probably want to use a `RecursiveArrayIterator->getDepth` and don't need to do dome `next`, `prev` magic...

Comment: Hi all. Sorry for not responding - have a quite important presention to prepare. Anyway will try your solutions and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Although I've had choppy results with them in the past you can use the below functions to move the current array pointer.

- prev() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php
- next() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php
- end() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php
- reset() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Hopefully that'll help.

Comment: +1 Right answer to the question, though probably the wrong approach to the problem.

Comment: Just replace `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` with `while(list($key, $value) = each($array))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($arr as $foo) {
    if (empty($isrewind)) {
       reset($arr);
       $isrewind = true;
    }

    echo "node: $foo\n";

    $copy = $arr;   // make a copy of the array
    $next = next($copy);
    echo "next: $next\n";

    $copy = $arr;   // make a copy of the array
    $prev = prev($copy);
    echo "prev: $prev\n";

    next($arr);     // don't forget to advance the pointer on the original array
}
```

I've demonstrated the `prev` bit just for the example. You can easily do that without `prev()` by saving the element at the end of each iteration.

The `if empty` bit resets the array pointer to the beginning, because `foreach` will advance the pointer once when it makes a copy of the array.

The above example yields:

```
node: 1
next: 2
prev: 

node: 2
next: 3
prev: 1

node: 3
next: 4
prev: 2

node: 4
next: 5
prev: 3

node: 5
next: 
prev: 4
```

If you have to do something like this though, there *might be* a better way just by rearranging your data structure (hard to tell without code).

Answer (score 0):

IHMO it's not possible with a simple foreach loop on an array that has non-numeric indexes. But you can extend the SPL class [CachingIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php) to wrap your array in this. In your extended class you can implement methods to return the previous and next index/value without advancing the internal element pointer.

If you have an array with numeric indexes use a for loop instead of a foreach. You can then use `$i+1` and `$i-1` to look at different array indexes than the current index.

Comment: can you explain this a bit? The page linked is unfinished

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what he asking for, but here's my shot

```
$list = array (
    'Home page' => null,
    'Articles'  => array (
        'Diving'    => null,
        'Skydiving' => null,
        'Stackoverflowing'  => null,
    ),
    'Nobody cares'  => array (
        'Hey'   => null,
        'It is just a test' => null,
    ),
);

function render_menu ($list)
{
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($y = new RecursiveArrayIterator ($list, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $key => $item)
    {
        if ($y->hasChildren ())
        {
            echo "<li>$key\n";
            render_menu ($item);
            echo "</li>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li>$key</li>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

render_menu ($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer staring me in the face. Retrieved the arrays I need like this:

> foreach ($tree as $key => $link) {
>
> $level = $link['level'];
>
> $next_key = $key+1;
>
> $prev_key = $key-1;
>
> $next_array = $tree[$next_key];
>
> $prev_array = $tree[$prev_key];

And then I could test the level property (indicating deph inside the navigation tree) with a buch of if statements to correctly insert the closing markup.

Messy code and I'm not proud of it, but it works!

Quite angry with myself for not seeing it before.

Comment: `>` is for quoting. To format lines as code, indent them four spaces. You can also use the '{}' button in the editor toolbar to toggle code formatting. Edit your answer now and try it. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score -3):

I assume you are using php. I dont think it's possible, you must know the index of element and index the array. Sth like this:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $element){
    echo $element;
    //do sth with $array[$i+1];
    //do sth with $array[$i-1];
    $i++;
}
```

Have no other clue

Comment: you don't think it's possible but you kind of give a solution? how does that work?

Comment: who deprecated `foreach ($array as $index => $element)` construct? :)

Comment: Ok, you're right. @Tharkun, I gave a workaroud not a real solution for the problem in my opinion